# Can't install zeroMQ on Mavericks

Tags: macos, install

I am starting with zeroMQ but could get it to work. I installed zeroMQ from tarball using the following commands:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pkg-config-0.23 --datarootdir=/usr/share
```

```
$ make
$ make check
$ sudo make install
```

While doing `make check` I got a few failures:

```
========================================
   zeromq 4.0.4: tests/test-suite.log
========================================

# TOTAL: 43
# PASS:  40
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 1
# FAIL:  2
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0

.. contents:: :depth: 2

FAIL: test_system
=================

W: Only able to create 253 sockets on this box
I: Tune your system to increase maximum allowed file handles
I: On OS/X, run 'ulimit -n 1200' in bash

XFAIL: test_abstract_ipc
========================

Assertion failed: (rc == 0), function main, file test_abstract_ipc.cpp, line 31.

FAIL: test_shutdown_stress
==========================

Assertion failed: (s2), function main, file test_shutdown_stress.cpp, line 64.
```

I want to use zeroMQ with Python on OS X

**UPDATE** **30-June**

so before you posted I tried with brew it sounded like everything went fine except `brew link zmq`

So tried to manually symlink

**cd /usr/local/opt**

**ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/4.0.3/lib/ zeromq**

**cd /usr/local/include/**

**ln -s ../Cellar/zeromq/4.0.3/include/zmq_utils.h zmq_utils.h**

**ln -s ../Cellar/zeromq/4.0.3/include/zmq.h zmq.h**

*then again i tried* : **sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install zmq -- --with-zmq-dir=/usr/local/opt/zeromq**

but got the following errors

checking for zmq.h... yes

checking for zmq_init() in -lzmq... yes

Cool, I found your zmq install...

creating Makefile

```
make "DESTDIR="

compiling rbzmq.c

rbzmq.c:968:7: error: use of undeclared identifier
'ZMQ_RECOVERY_IVL_MSEC'

        case ZMQ_RECOVERY_IVL_MSEC:

             ^

rbzmq.c:990:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_HWM'

    case ZMQ_HWM:

         ^

rbzmq.c:991:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_SWAP'

    case ZMQ_SWAP:

         ^

rbzmq.c:995:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_MCAST_LOOP'

    case ZMQ_MCAST_LOOP:

         ^

rbzmq.c:1292:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_HWM'

    case ZMQ_HWM:

         ^

rbzmq.c:1293:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_SWAP'

    case ZMQ_SWAP:

         ^

rbzmq.c:1297:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_MCAST_LOOP'

    case ZMQ_MCAST_LOOP:

         ^

rbzmq.c:1315:10: error: use of undeclared identifier
'ZMQ_RECOVERY_IVL_MSEC'

    case ZMQ_RECOVERY_IVL_MSEC:

         ^

rbzmq.c:1443:81: error: too few arguments to function call, expected
4, have 3

    send_args->rc = zmq_send(send_args->socket, send_args->msg, send_args->flags);

                    ~~~~~~~~                                                    ^

/usr/local/include/zmq.h:354:1: note: 'zmq_send' declared here

ZMQ_EXPORT int zmq_send (void *s, const void *buf, size_t len, int
flags);

^

/usr/local/include/zmq.h:67:27: note: expanded from macro 'ZMQ_EXPORT'

##       define ZMQ_EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))

                          ^

rbzmq.c:1517:38: error: too few arguments to function call, expected
4, have 3

        rc = zmq_send (s, &msg, flags);

             ~~~~~~~~                ^

/usr/local/include/zmq.h:354:1: note: 'zmq_send' declared here

ZMQ_EXPORT int zmq_send (void *s, const void *buf, size_t len, int
flags);

^

/usr/local/include/zmq.h:67:27: note: expanded from macro 'ZMQ_EXPORT'

##       define ZMQ_EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))

                          ^

rbzmq.c:1541:81: error: too few arguments to function call, expected
4, have 3

    recv_args->rc = zmq_recv(recv_args->socket, recv_args->msg, recv_args->flags);

                    ~~~~~~~~                                                    ^

/usr/local/include/zmq.h:356:1: note: 'zmq_recv' declared here

ZMQ_EXPORT int zmq_recv (void *s, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);

^

/usr/local/include/zmq.h:67:27: note: expanded from macro 'ZMQ_EXPORT'

##       define ZMQ_EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))

                          ^

rbzmq.c:1602:38: error: too few arguments to function call, expected
4, have 3

        rc = zmq_recv (s, &msg, flags);

             ~~~~~~~~                ^

/usr/local/include/zmq.h:356:1: note: 'zmq_recv' declared here

ZMQ_EXPORT int zmq_recv (void *s, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);

^

/usr/local/include/zmq.h:67:27: note: expanded from macro 'ZMQ_EXPORT'

#       define ZMQ_EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))

                          ^

rbzmq.c:1675:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_HWM'

    rb_define_const (zmq_module, "HWM", INT2NUM (ZMQ_HWM));

                                                 ^

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1167:35:
note: expanded from macro 'INT2NUM'

## define INT2NUM(v) INT2FIX((int)(v))

                                  ^

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:241:45:
note: expanded from macro 'INT2FIX'

#define INT2FIX(i) ((VALUE)(((SIGNED_VALUE)(i))<<1 | FIXNUM_FLAG))

                                            ^

rbzmq.c:1676:51: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_SWAP'

    rb_define_const (zmq_module, "SWAP", INT2NUM (ZMQ_SWAP));

                                                  ^

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1167:35:
note: expanded from macro 'INT2NUM'

# define INT2NUM(v) INT2FIX((int)(v))

                                  ^

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:241:45:
note: expanded from macro 'INT2FIX'

##define INT2FIX(i) ((VALUE)(((SIGNED_VALUE)(i))<<1 | FIXNUM_FLAG))

                                            ^

rbzmq.c:1683:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZMQ_MCAST_LOOP'

    rb_define_const (zmq_module, "MCAST_LOOP", INT2NUM (ZMQ_MCAST_LOOP));

                                                        ^

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1167:35:
note: expanded from macro 'INT2NUM'

## define INT2NUM(v) INT2FIX((int)(v))

                                  ^

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:241:45:
note: expanded from macro 'INT2FIX'

#define INT2FIX(i) ((VALUE)(((SIGNED_VALUE)(i))<<1 | FIXNUM_FLAG))

                                            ^

rbzmq.c:1698:64: error: use of undeclared identifier
'ZMQ_RECOVERY_IVL_MSEC'

    rb_define_const (zmq_module, "RECOVERY_IVL_MSEC", INT2NUM (ZMQ_RECOVERY_IVL_MSEC));

                                                               ^

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1167:35:
note: expanded from macro 'INT2NUM'

# define INT2NUM(v) INT2FIX((int)(v))

                                  ^

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:241:45:
note: expanded from macro 'INT2FIX'

#define INT2FIX(i) ((VALUE)(((SIGNED_VALUE)(i))<<1 | FIXNUM_FLAG))

                                            ^

16 errors generated.

make: *** [rbzmq.o] Error 1



Gem files will remain installed in
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/zmq-2.1.4 for inspection.
```

Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/zmq-2.1.4/./gem_make.out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this bugreport:

https://github.com/zeromq/zproto/issues/61

If you want to be able to build with those checks not failing, refer to that bugreport to see when a patch is made.

In the meantime, you either have to live without the functionality that fails, or fix the bug yourself.

Answer (score 1):

## Installing ZeroMQ with brew

Considering installing [ZeroMQ](https://github.com/zeromq) with the `brew` package manager. [brew](http://brew.sh) should deal with the build problems for you.

To install brew, run this command in **Terminal.app**:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Then install ZeroMQ using:

```
brew install zeromq
```

With ZeroMQ installed, you can follow the python specific steps on the [PyZMO page](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/wiki/Building-and-Installing-PyZMQ).

## Installing from source

Alternatively, try following the non-brew based approach documented on the official ZeroMQ page, [Building and Installing PyZMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/wiki/Building-and-Installing-PyZMQ).

## Log an Issue

As this problem does not appear to affect others, consider [logging an issue with PyZMO](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues) directly. There you will reach the core developers and their insight will hopefully quickly produce a solution.

Comment: Hi @Graham Miln, I already tried with brew before you posted an answer, however I got `brew link zmq` failure so I manually linked posted in updated question above.

Comment: Given the technical nature of the problem, you should log a new issue over at GitHub to engage the ZeroMQ developers directly. Hopefully they will quickly find the underlying cause.

Comment: Do you know how to get the .so file that is needed for it to work as a PHP extension? I've checked in `/usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/4.1.4/lib` but no .so there.

Comment: Have you tried [building ZeroMQ from source](http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software)? ZeroMQ's `make`, `make check`, and `make install` work well on macOS. Otherwise, please can you ask this as a question over on [StackOverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com).